# Making arrays of generic interfaces

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Let's say we have the following interface:

```
interface I<A extends string, B extends string> {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    c: `${A} ${B}`
}
```

I want to make a function which makes an array of `I` and validates its types so that

```
makeArr([
    {
        a: "1",
        b: "2",
        c: <- it should have type "1 2" | "3 4"
    },
    {
        a: "3",
        b: "4",
        c: <- it should have type "1 2" | "3 4"
    }
])
```

I have already tried implementing it like this:

```
type Arr<A extends string, B extends string> = I<A, B>[]

function makeArr<A extends string, B extends string>(arr: Arr<A, B>) {
    return arr
}
```

However, the `c` property still accepts any string

```
makeArr([
    {
        a: "1",
        b: "2",
        c: "this does not work"
    },
    {
        a: "3",
        b: "4",
        c: "whatever "
    }
])
```

It does a little bit better when you specify the types explicitly, but `c` accepts some wrong types anyway

```
makeArr<"1" | "3", "2" | "4">([
    {
        a: "1",
        b: "2",
        c: "3 2"
    },
    {
        a: "3",
        b: "4",
        c: "1 4"
    }
])
```

I also wouldn't like to specify it explicitly, because those arrays may be very long

Edit:
Thanks to aleksxor's answer I managed to implement it, however the types must be specified explicitly
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhA2kBOAeAKlCAPYEB2AJgM5QDeUAhgFxRHBICWeA5gDRQBGNdjLUAvgD4oAXigAKAFBQZUDNlyES5anIDaAcgoaAuuy7qNHXQKgB+GVNnWoAAwAkpNJu07+UR86O7+t6bIBKKisbGTwIADcIJH8ZAMl4ySZcJAAzCgBjaABJdEwcfGIySm56JjZOUt5mAWFSWJL1ACIKJr1K5o429gyaOERo9EFJfklJVIBXPAzgBgB7PCgAWwoAawgAQSRUeQKlYtUecv0q8trxCm2aXLRBNR0AsgakCGAJpEXLmNHJFfWt1ANeqhGSqJoAZiarAa1gMTQALE0GvwAD5AmGyMEAVihGJkcIAbEjrKNBOI1OiQY0IbiqXDEdCqb0oE0sVAicjGbJgSDsbSQYT+aFmRCoIjOZTeTQaVzQvShTYReCxcTZPxZU8qXyNbDpUSdbIRWyOSTJA8gA)

Answer (score 4):

I believe there must be a more elegant way. But here is my attempt to implement such a check:

```ts
type I<T extends { a: string, b: string }> = T extends {
    a: T['a'],
    b: T['b'],
    c: `${T['a']} ${T['b']}`
} ? T : never

function makeArr<T extends { a: string, b: string }>(arr: readonly [...I<T>[]]) {
    return arr
}

makeArr([
    {
        a: "1",
        b: "2",
        c: "doesn't pass"
    },
    {
        a: "3",
        b: "4",
        c: "3 4"
    }
])
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKkGKW)

Comment: I believe your solution is good and elegant enough. You did not see mine )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't work exactly as I wanted because when `[{ a: "1", b: "2", c: ... }, {a: "3", b: "4", c: ...}]` is passed to this function I wanted to be able to assign `1 2` or `3 4` to both `c` properties of this array's entries